# can't get HTML to display in Apple Mail signature

Tags: mail.app, signature, html

I'm stumped.  I cannot get the HTML I wrote to display!  I followed all the steps properly with creating a webarchive file, renaming so that it shows up in Apple Mail. But then when I go back in and see the signature, it's there but it doesn't display the HTML ... it just displays the code!

I've tested the HTML code on a webpage, and it works just fine.  I have my message format as Rich Text.

The code is:

```
<a href="http://www.tweetbars.com" ><img src="http://bar.tweetbars.com/azdesertfather.gif" /></a></center>
```

Comment: Have you seen this question elsewhere on here?: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1138/how-can-i-add-some-html-to-my-mail-app-signature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured out the problem, thanks to someone on the Apple forum!

When I was typing out the file in TextEdit, I needed to use the setting Format > Make Plain Text (or use a pure text editor like Text Wrangler).  That was messing up the whole process.  Now it's working!

Here's that thread:
http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=13095810#13095810

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify the steps you used so in case you missed something, take a look [at this page](http://bytes.com/topic/macosx/insights/825900-setup-html-signatures-apple-mail-mail-app) describing how to set up HTML mail signatures.

Comment: I followed all those steps exactly.  This is what I see when I look at the .webarchive file I made:  https://files.me.com/azdesertfather/yutxdw  I made it in TextEdit and saved as .webarchive, but I also tried doing it in Word as an .html then bringing that into Safari to make it a .webarchive.  Both ways, same weird problem...