# How can I embed a linked local image in an Apple Mail signature?

Tags: mail.app, email

I think my question says it all (and yes, I've googled and searched StackExchange already) - but to clarify:

I want to embed an image, which I have locally, in my html email signature (i.e. my logo, linked to my website). I create a html file (and made a web archive of it) with referencing to my local image like  `src="file:///Users/myuser/path/to/image/jpg"`.

Opening the web archive/html page in Safari displays the logo fine.

Now, when I use this html signature, **Thunderbird is smart enough to embed the local image properly with a binary mime type of image/jpeg, however, Mail just doesn't do anything with it and just leaves the html code untouched**, still referencing to the local file (and even that doesn't work/display when I receive my own mail on my Mac where I actually have the file at that local place; probably sandboxed?!).

I've already googled and all of below are not working:

[How can I embed an image in an Apple Mail signature?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1406/how-can-i-embed-an-image-in-an-apple-mail-signature)

[How can I add some html to my Mail.app signature?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1138/how-can-i-add-some-html-to-my-mail-app-signature)

(and their respective linked articles on the web).

The only way I could get the local image to display in the received email is to drag & drop the image from the Finder into the Mail signature preferences window, but then, I still have the problem that the image is not linked to my website, and I see now way to edit the html source of it in any way.

I've already tried to drag & drop the image, then open the web archive file under /Users/myuser/Library/Mail/Signatures in Safari, fetch the html code (which holds code for an embedded object), modify the source code (adding a link around the image), save it as web archive and overwrite the old file. However, after doing that and restarting Mail, the image doesn't show, but instead shows a place holder saying "Missing Plug-in".

(I don't want to use remote images on the web, since many clients mostly ask users to display remote images firstly, before actually displaying them - embedded images therefore work better, as they will be displayed instantly in most cases/email clients' default configuration.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution:

1. Open the picture in Preview (or open the html in a browser)
2. Cmd-A to select all, Cmd-C to copy
3. Create a new signature and paste in the contents

I have verified that this solution works for local pictures and simple html snippets.

Comment: I tried that but Mail seems to be messing up the html. For some reason it's unable to position multiple images beside each other. Seems like Mail.app is generating some improper html code (object embedding tags) that force a line break. See the screenshot here: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/706/emailsigu.png/, which shows my html sig both in Safari and (same html code) in Mail. Ridiculous how Mail is so far behind Thunderbird, but I guess I need to put the icons into a html table. Ugly... but I guess it's the only way...

Comment: Yes, when it comes to email, tables unfortunately still rule the day.

Comment: did not work for me at all...I got an image of a blank page. I can get it to work, but the minute I shut down - the next day the images are gone.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that Mac Mail does not allow for embedded images in their signatures. If you are designing an HTML signature, I would use the img src tag to load a remote image. Try using googleplus or googledocs to save the image you want to include. You can then control it using HTML and CSS styles.

Comment: If using this technique, bear in mind that most modern mail clients (and most security-conscious users) disable automatic loading of images from the internet by default. And some users (myself included) instruct their mail clients to display the plain text alternative to any HTML emails by default. To those recipients, your signature will not appear as intended.