# Formatting HTML signature in Mail (Lion)

Tags: macos, mail.app, signature

I have created an HTML signature with a local image. I have formatted the signature using a Table.

I have tried to add my signature to mail using the method described [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14015/how-can-i-embed-a-linked-local-image-in-an-apple-mail-signature), i.e. open the sig in a browser, Cmd+A on the browser and Cmv+V on the mail signature pane.

This appears to work, but when I go to use the signature the image formatting went bananas on me. Like shown on the pic bellow (mail on top and safari on bottom).

[image: Formatting Went Bananas]

I am not very knowledgable of HTML. But here is my code in case I have something wrong there.

```
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
    <td rowspan=3 style="padding-right:5px; border-right:solid 1px #7F7F7F;">
        <img src="waveform-logo_no_quote.png" /> <BR>
    </td>
    <td style="padding-left:5px;">
        <font face="Arial" color="#0F243E"><b>Tiago Veloso</b></font> 
        <span style="font-variant: small-caps;"> <font face="Arial" color="#404040"> / Junior Software Engineer </font> </span> <BR>
    </td>
<tr>
    <td style="padding-left:5px;">
        <span style="font-variant: small-caps;"> <font face="Arial" color="#404040"> t: </font> </span> 
            <font face="Arial" color="#0F243E"> [+XYZ] 555-555-123 </font> <BR>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="padding-left:5px;">
        <span style="font-variant: small-caps;"> <font face="Arial" color="#404040"> e: </font> </span>
        <font face="Arial"> <a href="mailto:mail@example.com">mail@example.com</a> </font> <BR>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align=right style="padding-right:5px; border-right:solid 1px #7F7F7F">
        <font face="Arial" color="#7F7F7F"><i>adding possibilities</i></font>
    </td>
    <td style="padding-left:5px;">
        <span style="font-variant: small-caps;"> <font face="Arial" color="#404040"> w: 
            </font> </span> <font face="Arial"> <a href="http://www.website.com">www.website.com</a> </font> <BR>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: If I may inject something a little off-topic, I would *strongly* encourage you *not* to do that in emails. Most people view emails in plain text, and will not only miss out on the formatting, but receive your image as an attachment. I have never known anyone in a corporate setting to have anything positive to say about mini web pages in signatures. You won't be impressing anyone with this and will likely upset a large subset of people you email. Just a suggestion before you implement this. A simple, plain text signature really is the best way to go.

Comment: I know, and agree with you. I was asked to use the same signature as my colleagues, they did theirs in MS Outlook. I can't copy and edit theirs, the text formatting as well as the image goes funky. HTML formatting was the closest I could get.

Comment: I would suggest you to stay on a short text only signature. This is much more professionnal and respectful of your contacts in search of efficiency. For example: I can't wait any image load in my E-mail, my brain have already switched to another space, and my fingers obeyed within the 50 ms (because they are slow :)).

Answer (score 2):

If your code is copied and pasted, the first thing I realize is the following:

```
<span style="font-variant: small-caps;"> <font face="Arial" color="#404040"> / Junior Software Engineer </font> </span> <BR>
    </td>
<tr>
    <td style="padding-left:5px;">
```

which means, the end tag

```
</tr>
```

is missing. This might be the problem due to different renderings between mail and Safari.
It's worth a try.

Comment: Good catch, but still the same end result.